# Where can I find SPF record information for Network Solution hosted email?

Tags: email

I have a client who has their e-mail hosted with Network Solutions and some of the e-mails they are sending are going to spam.

I've searched Google for information on network solutions and SPF records but all the results have to do with "how to set up an SPF record" - which I understand how to do.

The problem is that I can't find any information about what SPF records to use for network solutions hosted e-mail.

I even tried lookup up spf records on `networksolutions.com` but it appears there are none.

Where can I find SPF record information for Network Solution hosted email?

Answer (score 3):

This one is easy, you will set it up similar to the way Google does it..

Network solutions uses "Messagelabs.com" as it's MX.

If you look up message lab SPF record, you'll notice their SPF record.

http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnslookup/spf/messagelabs.com/

They use,

```
v=spf1 include:spf.messagelabs.com ~all
```

So in your SPF record just put that include in it..

```
include:spf.messagelabs.com
```

Then you can test it by sending an email to those SPF authentication testing programs, that auto-respond to your email letting you know if you have everything set up right.

Like

```
 Mailtest [at] unlocktheinbox.com
```

and

```
check-auth [at] verifier.port25.com
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer comes up high on Google search so I thought I'd give an update.

I don't believe the above is true any more. I talked with NetSol email support department at the SPF they gave me is this:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.netsolmail.net ~all
```

Hope that helps.